# What is the purpose of narwals' tusks?

Tags: evolution, animal-models

I've heard that narwals can grow their tusks up to 16 ft long. What do they need the tusk for? Hunting?  Comunication?

Comment: Probably for male mate competition, but nobody knows really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evidence shows that the tusk is innervated, and acts as a sensory organ to the outside environment, as well as a mating tool.

[Sensory ability in the narwhal tooth organ system](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ar.22886/abstract;jsessionid=C9F42D853D1319AAF960E61727E80456.f03t03)

Comment: Nice finding, this paper will help a lot I guess! If it is an sensor organ, I'd be curious to hear more about why it is present only in males. Would be great if someone could make a short summary of the different hypotheses of how this organ evolved. In the abstract of the paper you linked, they also say `New findings of sexual foraging divergence [..] add to the discussion of the functional significance of the narwhal tusk.` So, it seems that this organ may also eventually be involved in foraging behaviour.